# Unable to change navigation bar color during runtime via code?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I tested against iOS 14.5

We would like to provide ability to change the navigation bar color during runtime.

However, I notice the following code no longer has any effect.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

But, if I did it directly in Storyboard, it works just fine.

[image]

---

We would like to have ability to change the various different color during runtime (via user button clicked)

Does anyone has any idea why the above code broken?

Thanks.

p/s I can confirm the `navigationController` is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 13 & above, you have to use new `UINavigationBarAppearance` api to get the correct color.

```
public extension UINavigationBar {

    func applyPlainAppearanceFix(barTintColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor) {
        
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = barTintColor
            
            self.standardAppearance = appearance
            self.compactAppearance = appearance
            self.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
        }
        
        self.isTranslucent = false
        self.barTintColor = barTintColor
        self.backgroundColor = barTintColor
        self.tintColor = tintColor
    }

}
```

From the call site it should look like

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.applyPlainAppearanceFix(barTintColor: .red, tintColor: .white)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding this in your AppDelegate and I think it will work, if you didn't want it for all the app then your code is working fine, I've used it and it's working like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: But, we would like to let user change it to various color after the app shown, via button clicked. Hence, placing the code in AppDelegate doesn't fit into our case.

Comment: your code is working fine, I've tried it, check answer update

Comment: That is not solid red color. Try to turn off "Translucent" just below the Navigation Bar style.

Comment: so the issue is to make it a solid color? or the same color the user picked?

Comment: The user is going to pick UIColor.red, so we need to show #ff0000 but not a semi-transparent red.